# Will use of isolation transformer advise in lightning prone area?

Tags: isolation, surge-protection, lightning

I am working on a Radio Station located on a hill top. There are frequent lightning strikes during the monsoon season and they sometimes damage electrical equipment inspite of providing earthing. I am planning to install surge suppressors, line suppressors. Will an isolation transformer be useful in this case?

Comment: Any break in conductors (ie, isolation transformer) will improve your resilience to nearby strikes. Nothing will protect your equipment from a direct strike.

Comment: There are entire BOOKS on this topic. I have one of the best somewhere around this place. I'll look. If I find the darned thing, I will provide the title and author. But the gist of what I gained from it is that serious lightning protection involves ***four*** stages of very different kinds of protection. Think of them as rings or moats. The lightning has to get through the outer moat before getting to the next moat. In the process, has lost some of its potency. Each ring is designed to handle a certain aspect. Finally, at the inner ring you have the usual protections arranged. I'll look.

Comment: I also think ARRL has something on the topic. But, memory serving, it wasn't quite as good as this other book I have laying about somewhere.

Comment: See perhaps this book "Lightning Protection (Iet Power and Energy)" by Vernon Cooray, 6th chapter.